# Installing matplotlib-venn

Tags: python, windows, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-venn

I have a problem using easy-install or pip for installing matplotlib-venn. I'm on a windows computer using python2.7. However, the cmd shows there's always some errors.

This is the windows using "easy_install", I typed in the command $easy_install matplotlib-venn in cmd, then it shown error:

```
"no lapack/blas resources found ".`
```

Then when I used pip to install, typed in command $pip install matplotlib-venn in cmd, it shown:

```
    Command ""C:\Python27\New Folder\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize
;__file__='c:\\users\\qiu\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-cz2ob6\\scipy\\setup.
py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n'
, '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\qiu\appdata\local\temp\pi
p-tfwzxc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\qiu\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-cz2ob6\s
cipy
```

---

Comment: How did you install `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 8):

An alternative is to use the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) Python distribution, which includes more than 300 of the most popular Python packages for science, math, engineering, and data analysis (including NumPy, and matplotlib), and avoids many such headaches.

Installing `matplotlib-venn` on it was straightforward (`pip install matplotlib-venn`).

This command can be run from an IPython/Jupyter notebook cell by starting with [the bang](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html?highlight=exclamation#shell-assignment): `!pip install matplotlib-venn`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct solution for your problem, but a possible workaround.

[Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/) provides an [extensive list of pre-compiled python packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for Windows. For instance, those which are dependent on the lapack/blas libraries are already compiled against the [Intel MKL libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library).